# parallel execution with a fixed order

Tags: macos, shell, time, gnu-parallel, optimathsat

```
#!/bin/bash
doone() {
    tracelength="$1"
    short="$2"
    long="$3"
    ratio="$4"
    echo "$tracelength $short $long $ratio" >> results.csv
    python3 main.py "$tracelength" "$short" "$long" "$ratio" >> file.smt2
    gtime -f "%U" /Users/Desktop/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2
}
export -f doone
step=0.1
parallel doone \
         ::: 200 300 \
         :::: <(seq 0 $step 0.2) \
         ::::+ <(seq 1 -$step 0.8) \
         :::: <(seq 0 $step 0.1) \
         ::: {1..2} &> results.csv
```

I need the data given in the results.csv to be in order.  Every job prints  its inputs which are the 3 variable mentioned at the beginning : **$tracelength**, **$short**, **$long** and **$ratio**, and then the associated execution time of that job; all in one line. So far my results look something like this:

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
200 0 1 0
200 0 1 0.1
200 0.1 0.9 0
```

how can I fix the order? and why is the execution time always **0.00**? **file.smt2** is a big file, and in no way can the execution time be **0.00**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really a bad idea to append to the same file in parallel. You are going to have race conditions all over the place.

You are doing that with both `results.csv` and `file.smt2`.

So if you write to a file in `doone` make sure it is has a unique name (e.g. by using `myfile.$$`).

To see if race conditions are your problem, you can make GNU Parallel run one job at a time: `parallel --jobs 1`.

If the problem goes away by that, then you can probably get away with:

```
doone() {
    tracelength="$1"
    short="$2"
    long="$3"
    ratio="$4"
    # No >> is needed here, as all output is sent to results.csv
    echo "$tracelength $short $long $ratio"
    tmpfile=file.smt.$$
    cp file.smt2 $tmpfile
    python3 main.py "$tracelength" "$short" "$long" "$ratio" >> $tmpfile
    # Be aware that the output from gtime and optimathsat will be put into results.csv - making results.csv not a CSV-file
    gtime -f "%U" /Users/Desktop/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < $tmpfile
    rm $tmpfile
}
```

If `results.csv` is just a log file, consider using `parallel --joblog my.log` instead.